# C++ Initialize Variable in .data Section

Tags: c++, visual-studio, variables, optimization

I'm asking myself, how you could improve code. If encountered following problem:

```
int i = 10;
int s = i * 12;

int main(){ }
```

When you look at the code in the PE-format, you notice, that neither i nor s is declared in the .data segment, despite the fact that their value could have been precalculated. They get initialized in runtime.

Here I have an example of another Code which has the same phenomenon. The Values were also declared like in the example above

View in Debugger before passing EntryPoint:

```
0133BF7C  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................  
0133BF8C  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
```

After passing the EntryPoint:

```
0133BF7C  E9 01 00 00 DF 02 00 00 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  é...ß...d.......
0133BF8C  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
```

How can I declare a variable with an initial value in .data Section in C++ to save the precious computation time?

Or is the .data section never initialized with something before the execution starts?

Comment: use `constexpr` ? At that, worrying about optimization is usually a waste of time for the little stuff.

Comment: I believe if you make variables i and s static, they will get placed in the .data segment. Alternatively, if they're constant, you can use constexpr over static.

Comment: A proper optimizing compiler would just delete all of that. Always test performance related stuff with *optimized* builds.

Comment: I have a feeling you're looking at Debug code and in that case it's all for nothing.

Comment: @Acorn thanks it worked out

Comment: I would add that the MS compiler will usually respect `constexpr` in a debug build.

Comment: From [Special Sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#special-sections): *".data: Initialized data - .bss: Uninitialized data"*. So yes, .data stores initialized data. Since you made sure that your variables are mutable, I see no reason why the linker shouldn't initialized them to some arbitrary value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are compile time constants, use [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).

```
constexpr int i = 10;
constexpr int s = i * 12;
```

Starting in C++17 these are also `inline` variables so you can declare them in a header file and not worry about having multiple definitions.

If these are not constants, but you want them to be constant initialized, then you can at least use `static` to make them have internal linkage which makes the optimization more likely to happen. Starting in C++20 you can use [`constinit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constinit) to specify that the variable is to have static initialization, but can be changed later on in the program.

Comment: True, got sidetracked by `constinit`, which doesn't declare a constant.